# X-axis not showing up

Tags: r, time-series

When plotting my time series I cannot seem to get my months to plot on the x-axis. It works when I use years but I want months.
[Air Passenger Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WPhmj.jpg). Here is my code below:

Monthly totals (thousands) of international airline passengers in the U.S. are given form January 1949-December 1960.

Numbers

```
data(AirPassengers)
year <- seq(1949, 1960, 1)
months <- seq(0, 144, 1)
x.t <- AirPassengers
plot.ts(x.t, ylab = "Passengers (thousands)", xlab = "Year", xaxt = "n", xaxs = 'i')
axis(1, at = months)
title(main = "International Airline Passengers\n 1949-1960")
```

My apologies, I haven't used stack exchange before.

Comment: If anyone is wondering, this data is just `data(AirPassengers)` by the looks of it, so this can be reproduced.

Comment: @NightOwl888 - The `AirPassenger` data is routinely used in the R tag when dealing with time-series questions, as it is included with the program. A minor edit will take care of supplying the data, making it perfectly answerable.

Answer (score 0):

When you plot this ts, your x-axis limits are the numeric values from 1949 to 1961. So putting a tick at 0 to 144 gives you nothing as it is way outside your plot range. Instead, you want a month-by-month label as per the original timeseries monthly reporting. `time` will give you those points:

```
time(x.t)

#          Jan      Feb      Mar      Apr ...
#1949 1949.000 1949.083 1949.167 1949.250 ...
#1950 1950.000 1950.083 1950.167 1950.250 ...
```

Therefore, you can try:

```
axis(1, at = time(x.t))
```